# Constant expression contains invalid operations error in accessing env value Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, static

I have a problem in my project. I want to access my env value data in a private static variable but found error `Constant expression contains invalid operations`. Could not know how to solve this.
Here is my code

```
private static $session_link = [
    'local' => env('LOCAL_URL'),
    'production' => env('PRODUCTION_URL')
];
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to write code like this. As described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

The only way you can make this work is:

```
private static $session_link = [];

public function __construct()
{
    self::session_link = [
        'local' => env('LOCAL_URL'),
        'production' => env('PRODUCTION_URL')
    ]; 
}
```

**TL;DR:**

That happens because PHP runs your code twice: first, it's running to compile your code, to read all methods and properties, and only after it runs second time to run compiled code. During compilation, PHP doesn't know about `env()` function, that's why it throws an `\Error`.